# C++ UBSAN produces false positives with derived objects

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, ubsan

I wanted to use UBSAN (undefined behavior sanitizer) but found it completely worthless as it reports to many false positives.

E.g. a simple `std::make_shared<int>(42);` is enough to trigger warnings like

> member access within address 0x00000236de70 which does not point to an object of type '_Sp_counted_base'

Reducing this example to a MWE shows that the problem is more general with base classes and inheritance:

Example:

```
struct Foo{
    int f(){ return g(); }
    virtual int g() = 0;
};

struct Bar: Foo{
    int g(){ return 42; }
};

int main(){
    auto f = new Bar();
    return f->g();
}
```

Compile with `-fsanitize=undefined` and watch

> example.cpp:15:16: runtime error: member call on address 0x000000726e70 which does not point to an object of type 'Bar'
>
> 0x000000726e70: note: object has invalid vptr

See https://godbolt.org/z/0UiVtu.

How are not even these simple cases properly handled? Did I miss anything? How should I properly use UBSAN to check my code? (This requires [almost] no false positives)

Edit: As it seems the MWE only works on godbolt, the original code looks like this:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
using MMStream = boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source>;

int main(){
  MMStream stream;
  stream.open("a.out");
  return !stream;
}
```

Compile with `clang++-8 -fsanitize=undefined -fvisibility=hidden -I /opt/boost_1_64_0/include/ test.cpp /opt/boost_1_64_0/lib/libboost_iostreams.so` and run which results in errors like

> runtime error: member call on address 0x00000126ef30 which does not point to an object of type 'boost::detail::sp_counted_base'

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Have you tried it on your machine or only on godbolt.org? It's possible that the system on godbolt.org is configured such that ubsan fails.

Comment: That is interesting. I'm also having trouble with UBSan, but on my program, and only under gcc. clang's sanitizers work OK

I've found a lot of discussions on simular topics, e.g.: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39191

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: It happens on all compilers although I noticed that the MWE only worked on godbolt. I produced the MWE by using my original code and subsequently stripping it down to the bare essentials that still produced the bug on godbolt to try different compilers and for people to play with it. Seems behavior there is indeed different, so I attached the original MWE which together with the link lead me to the cause. Not really satisfied with "Upgrade Boost" as a solution, but well...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trying to answer this myself after the comments and creating another MWE.

TLDR: Make sure all classes containing virtual functions are exported when compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`

Consider a shared library Foo with

foo.h

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

struct Foo{
    virtual int g() = 0;
};

struct Bar: Foo{
    int g(){ return 42; }
};

EXPORT Foo* create();
```

foo.cpp
    #include "foo.h"

```
Foo* create(){
  return new Bar();
}
```

Compiled with `clang++-8 foo.cpp -shared -fPIC -o foo.so`

And an executable linked against this using the virtual functions but with `-fvisibility`:

main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
  Foo* f  = create();
  return f->g() != 42;
}
```

Compiled with `clang++-8 -fsanitize=undefined -fvisibility=hidden main.cpp foo.so`

This will report

> runtime error: member call on address 0x00000290cea0 which does not point to an object of type 'Foo'

This is the same error as described in https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39191 (thanks @Nikita Petrenko)

Summary: With `fvisibility=hidden` not exported symbols (functions, classes not decorated with the attribute `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` are not considered the same when used in different DSOs (e.g. executable and shared library). Hence the base class `Foo` in the shared library and the executable are distinct (they have different vtables) which UBSAN detects: The executable "expects" an object witg vtable of `Exe::Foo` but instead gets `Library::Foo`

In the boost case the class `sp_counted_base` is the culprit as it is not exported until Boost 1.69 which adds `BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT`, so switching to Boost 1.69+ fixes the issue.